# Rails 3 and Active Record Query - 2 informations in one query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I am trying to find a way, how to get the statement of data in database (this is simple) and how to get the count of items. I am struggling with this problem a whole day and have not an idea, how to solve it...

I have following structure:

```
ID: first: second: name:
1    2      5       Emma
2    2      5       Emma
3    3      4       Luis
4    5      2       Mark
```

I want to get following statement:

```
Emma
Luis
Mark
```

This is easy. But to each of the name I would like to add the information about the count of rows in database, for this example it would be like:

```
Emma 2
Luis 1
Mark 1
```

The first statement is possible to get with a query **Model.where("some condition")**, but I don't know, how to get the second statement...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you may use count method like `Model.where("some condition").count & you`ll get it

Comment: but if I will use `Model.where("some condition").count`, so I will get the count of lines only and I would need the count of lines and the data (Emma, Luis, Mark)

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.group(:name).count
```

This should return

```
{"Emma" => 2, "Luis" => 1, "Mark" => 1}
```

Comment: I am thinking about it... but this query will return me only two columns, or not? Is possible to return all columns?

Comment: Why would you want all the columns when you have an aggregate function like `count`? It makes sense only when the columns selected are also part of the group_by clause.

Comment: Because between this table and the another table is the relationship. So I will use `@data=Model.group(:name).count` and the in `view` I need to use `data.RELATIONSHIP.COLUMN_FROM_ANTH_TABLE`. Now if I will use `data.RELATIONS.COLUMN_FROM_ANTH_TABLE`, so I will get the error about `undefined method `RELATIONS' for [.., ..]:Array`. I am sorry, I am newbie and maybe I disregard other important thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
User.select('users.*, count(*) AS times').group(:name)
```

In that case you have all attributes of User model + times which is count of name attribute.